# Chai.should() makes Mocha explode

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I try to use Chai Should style assertions, but the following statement makes Mocha explode. Here is my complete Require block:

```
/**                                         
 * Module dependencies.                     
 */                                         
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),         
  User = mongoose.model('User'),            
  moment = require('moment'),               
  SSEvent = mongoose.model('Event'),        
  chai = require('chai');                   

chai.use(require('chai-datetime'));         
var should = chai.should();
```

Error message:

```
Running "mochaTest:src" (mochaTest) task
>> Mocha exploded!
>> TypeError: chai.should is not a function
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sebastianweikart/Desktop/dev/conftool-nga-mean/modules/events/tests/server/events.server.model.tests.js:13:19)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>>     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
>>     at /Users/sebastianweikart/Desktop/dev/conftool-nga-mean/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
```

What could possibly be the problem? 
I use 
    `"chai": "^3.5.0"` and   `"mocha": "~2.4.5"` which should be the latest stable versions..

Update:

I now added the following simple stripped down test - and it still explodes:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();



/**
 * Unit tests
 */
describe('Chai Should Test', function () {

  describe('Chai Should() should work', function () {
    it('Chai Should() must work', function (done) {
      var spartacus = 'spartacus';
      should.exist(spartacus);
      done();
    });

  });
});



Running "mochaTest:src" (mochaTest) task
>> Mocha exploded!
>> TypeError: chai.should is not a function
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sebastianweikart/Desktop/dev/conftool-nga-mean/modules/events/tests/server/chai.should.test.js:7:19)
```

Comment: There's something missing in your question. I'm able to run your example test without any error.

Answer (score 5):

make sure should.js is uninstalled in the project. Conflict occurs when should.js and chai.should is used together

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are not also requiring the `should` package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/should.

Answer (score 0):

If you are correctly importing `chai` it doesn't seem as if there's a problem.

The chai docs state:

> With the should require, the function is [...] executed.

So if you have a valid `chai` object, it will have a `shoudld()` function attached. You can verify this by [testing it live on tonic dev](https://tonicdev.com/56b0afb63abefb0c0020d78b/56b0afb63abefb0c0020d78c).

You should also try to remove the `chai.use(require('chai-datetime'));` statement - this could be overriding chais original properties and removing the `should()` function.

If you are still having problems it is likely being caused by something else - in which case we'd need to see / know more about your project.

Comment: if I remove var should = chai.should(); it works. I use should assertions further down the line in the file - for example savedEvent.title.should.equal('MyEvent');       This also works without problems: var assert = chai.assert;

Comment: thanks, I removed chai-datetime-  it's still exploding :(

Comment: Remove **everything** except the chai import and chai.should(). What happens?

Comment: it goes through as long as I don't use statements like should.not.exist(err); or  should.exist(err);  - they are the reasons why I want to include the should() function. Obviously I could use a different syntax as a workaround, but I want to get on the bottom of this..

Comment: If you want help, **please** provide an actual example if the code you are trying, **including** the require statements and the attempts to use `should.not.exist` etc, and **without** anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

But I just imported should in this way `const should = chai.should;` instead of `const should = chai.should();`

Answer (score -1):

I used

`chai.Should()`

instead of

`chai.should()`

as a temporary fix, since the project I'm working on currently requires a package that requires the should package, which interferes with chai. Chai exports with both `.should` and `.Should`, and they refer to the same function, `loadShould()` which is what we're invoking.